# gcc is installed but don't know how to fix

Tags: software-installation

The following is the output on my terminal. And I don't know how to fix. 
Any ideas?

```
~$ sudo apt install gcc g++
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
g++ is already the newest version (4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.2).
gcc is already the newest version (4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.2).
gcc set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

~$ whereis gcc
gcc: /usr/bin/gcc /usr/lib/gcc /usr/share/man/man1/gcc.1.gz

~$ whereis g++
g++: /usr/bin/g++ /usr/share/man/man1/g++.1.gz

~$ /usr/bin/gcc -version
bash: /usr/bin/gcc: No such file or directory

~$ cd /usr/bin

/usr/bin$ gcc -version
Command 'gcc' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install gcc

/usr/bin$ g++ -version
Command 'g++' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install g++
```

Comment: I tried whereis and gave me where it is located on my desk. but when I apply which doesn't give me any output. I need to add the path of the excutable gcc and g++

Comment: Naive guess, but can you try `sudo apt install --reinstall gcc g++`? That should help in case the files were manually deleted somehow after the package was installed.

Comment: sudo apt install --reinstall gcc g++, I tried this and I got new error..>>amani@amani-GT72S-6QE:~/Downloads$ sudo apt install --reinstall gcc g++

dpkg: error processing package gcc (--configure):
 installed gcc package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of g++:
 g++ depends on gcc (>= 4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.2); however:
  Package gcc is not configured yet.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full output of that command. The little I can see from your snippet in the comment suggests that there are much more severe problems on your system that are causing this.

Comment: Could it just be that `/usr/bin/gcc` and `/usr/bin/g++` are broken / dangling symlinks?

Comment: I have have gcc-6 and g++-6 in /usr/bin but i can't get any luck to find a way to work this out

Comment: So you have a few options (1) (re)-install the default `gcc-7` and `g++-7` packages for your system; (2) manually create symlinks from `gcc-6`/`g++-6` to the respective `/usr/bin/gcc` and `/usr/bin/g++` (3) use `update-alternatives` to create/maintain the symlinks for you. Unless you specifically need for `gcc` to be `gcc-6` I would do (1) as it's the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

Full word options must be preceded by two hyphens, while a single hyphen precedes a single letter option.

**Example:**

Instead of `gcc -version` try either `gcc -v` or `gcc --version`
Instead of `g++ -version` try either `g++ -v` or `g++ --version`

**From my computer:**

```
subroot@subroot:~$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

subroot@subroot:~$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-5 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 

subroot@subroot:~$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

subroot@subroot:~$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-5 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 
subroot@subroot:~$
```

**Help menu**
For more options, please type:

```
gcc --help
g++ --help
```

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that Bash reports the gcc/g++ executables are not there, even though the package is installed. And as I gather from the last comment, there seem to be a lot more problems underlying.

Comment: this doesn't work as well.amani@amani-GT72S-6QE:~/Downloads$ gcc -v

Command 'gcc' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install gcc

amani@amani-GT72S-6QE:~/Downloads$ gcc --help

Command 'gcc' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install gcc

amani@amani-GT72S-6QE:~/Downloads$ gcc -help

Command 'gcc' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install gcc